# codesign timestamp is not working inside a MacOS VM

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, codesign, code-signing-certificate

I'm trying to use codesign inside a MacOS VM:

```
codesign --sign "Developer ID Application: XXX (XXX)" myapp.dmg
```

I get the following error:

```
The timestamp service is not available.
```

The same usage on a real Mac is working. I suspect that MacOS inside a VM (so without real hardware) is limited for timestamping - the same way as it doesn't seem possible to sign in with an Apple account inside a MacOS VM.

Confirmation? Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I had some bad proxy settings. It can work.